# Male cat suddenly aggressive towards female cat with whom he has been together for more than a year

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression, outdoor, domestication

I have 2 outdoor cats, A male and another female. Both were very friendly and have had a litter too around 4 months ago. They are together since more than a year. They were very playful and shared food too. But since yesterday, the male has started to fight with the female. He is hissing, attacking and biting the female cat. If I try to negotiate he is hissing at me too. I tried to divert their attention by giving food to them separately. But the male cat seems to be more interested in attacking the female cat rather than eating. Until yesterday both were very friendly. Suddenly he has become this much aggressive and changed behaviour and I don't know why.

I thought of taking him to a vet but he isn't even coming in hand. He is just trying to attack when I try picking him up.

Please let me know what can be done to calm him down.

How did he turn so much violent towards a cat with whom he has been so friendly.?

Please help.

Comment: How old is your male cat? Was he neutered after the litter they had?

Comment: He is around 6 years old. He hasn't been neutered. He was a feral cat. I adopted him just 1 and a half year ago. It took me nearly 7-8 months just to get him to get adapted to human touch.

Comment: Very sudden changes in behavior are often a reason to see the vet. He could be in pain or have some nutritional deficit that makes him feel like he must defend his territory. It could also be that he now perceives his own litter as competition and becomes more and more aggressive to chase the kittens away.